# Find the limit of sequence ${x_{n}} = (\frac {n}{n+\ln(n)})^{\ln(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the limit of sequence $x_{n}$ such that $${x_{n}} = \left(\frac {n}{n+\ln(n)}\right)^{\ln(n)}$$
After some transformations we have $$a_{n}=\frac{- (\ln n)^2}{n + \ln n}$$
We have to prove that limit of $a_{n}$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ is equal to 0

Comment: $ln^2(n)<n+ln (n) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write $$x_n = \bigg(1 - \frac{\ln n}{n+ \ln n}\bigg)^{\ln n} = \Bigg[\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{\frac{n +\ln n}{\ln n}} \bigg)^{-\frac{n+ \ln n}{\ln n}} \Bigg]^ \frac{- (\ln n)^2}{n + \ln n}$$
Then just use the limit $$\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{a_n} \bigg)^{a_n} \to e \text{ as } a_n \to \infty$$ and the fact the the outer exponent goes to $0$.

Comment: I didn't get about limit of $$a_{n}=\frac{- (\ln n)^2}{n + \ln n}$$

Comment: That is $\frac{-(\ln n)^2}{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{\ln n}{n}} \to 0$ since powers are infinite of order greater than logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\ln(x_n)=-\ln(n)\ln(1+\frac{\ln(n)}{n})
\sim \frac{-1}{n}$$

the limit of $x_n$  is $1$ if we remember that

$$\ln(1+X)\sim X\;\; (X\to 0)$$
and $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$
{x_{n}} = (\frac {n}{n+ln(n)})^{ln(n)}
$

Looking at the reciprocal,
for large enough $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
(\frac {n+ln(n)}{n})^{ln(n)}
&=(1+\frac {ln(n)}{n})^{ln(n)}\\
&=\exp(\ln(n)\ln(1+\frac {ln(n)}{n}))\\
&<\exp(\ln(n)(\frac {ln(n)}{n}))
\qquad\text{since } \ln(1+x) < x\\
&=\exp(\frac {ln^2(n)}{n})\\
&<\frac1{1- \frac{ln^2(n)}{n}}
\qquad\text{since } e^x < \frac1{1-x} \text{ for } 0 < x < 1\\
&<1+2 \frac{ln^2(n)}{n}
\qquad\text{since } \frac1{1-x} < 1+2x \text{ for } 0 < x < \frac12\\
\end{array}
$

By the generalized Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+\frac{ln(n)}{n})^{ln(n)}
> 1+\frac{ln^2(n)}{n}$.

Actually,
$(1+\frac{ln(n)}{n})^{ln(n)}
> 1$
is enough.

Therefore
the limit is $1$.